# Python how to check/compare the dictionary list type that return single or multiple values

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have below two kinds of dictionary list that returns key value based on some operation , from which i need to check the type of dictionary

```
operation1 - test_dict=[{'name':['john','hari','ram'], 'id':['213','222','342']}]

operation2: test_dict=[{'name':'john', 'id':'213'}]
```

if i check the length of both case, it will return 1

```
print(len(test_dict))
```

#Expected:
i want to perform certain task based on the type of dictionary that return

```
if type (dict) that return == operation1:
  do task1
else:            ### that return == operation2
  do task 2
```

Appreciated if anybody can help on this

Comment: Hi @Axe319 that didn't help to differentiate the dictionary

Comment: Do you expect all items in operation1 to be lists? or any one of the key to be a list?

Comment: @cloud_hari If you always expect them to have a `'name'` key, `if isinstance(test_dict[0]['name'], list)` would tell you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check it like this:

Iterate through each of the items in the list, then check if each of the values in the dictionary are lists or not. If all the values in the dictionary are lists, then it is operation1 (per your definition) else, it is operations2.

```
def check_operations(test):
    if all(isinstance(v, list) for t in test for v in t.values()):
        return 'operation1'
    else: 
        return 'operation2'
test_dict=[{'name':['john','hari','ram'], 'id':['213','222','342']}]

print (check_operations(test_dict))

test_dict=[{'name':'john', 'id':'213'}]

print (check_operations(test_dict))
```

Here's the output for this:

```
operation1
operation2
```

If you think operation1 may have at least one list, you can change the if statement to `any` instead of `all`. With `all`, I am checking if all the values in the dictionary are lists.